# Application Didn't Work untill i restart visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-webapi

i have implemented web app in asp.net core using visual studio 2017.
There i am facing an issue when i open visual studio and run that application i got this error in popup see this image [image: Popup Show this error message]
[image: Error Detail Image]
**when i close my visual studio and restart it then it work fine it creating problem only first time when i run application**

Comment: can you show your web.config

Comment: using asp.net core .... no web.config there

Comment: Thats wrong. A web.config file is required when you host the app in IIS or IIS-Express. web.config turns on the AspNetCoreModule in IIS to launch your app. Settings in web.config enable the AspNetCoreModule in IIS to launch your app and configure other IIS settings and modules. If you are using Visual Studio and delete web.config, Visual Studio will create a new one. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration)